# MySQL Query which require multiple joins

Tags: mysql

I have a system that is used to log kids' their behavior. If a child is naughty it is logged as negative and if it has a well behaviour it is logged as positive.

For instance - if a child is rude it gets a 'Rude' negative and this is logged in the system with minus x points.

My structure can be seen in this sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46904

In the `users_rewards_logged` table, the `reward_id` column is a foreign key linked to either the deductions OR achievements table depending on the type of column.
If type is 1 is a **deduction reward**, if the type value is 2 is a **achievement reward**.

I basically want a query to list out something like this:

```
  +------------------------------+
  |   reward   | points  | count |
  +------------------------------+
  | Good Work  |   100   |   1   |
  |    Rude    |   -50   |   2   |
  +------------------------------+
```

So it tallys up the figures and matches the reward depending on type (1 is a deduction, 2 is a achievement)

What is a good way to do this, based on the sqlfiddle?

Comment: FKs can't be to multiple tables (if you were to have MySQL enforce the constraints, you'd find it impossible to define)—this violates the [principle of orthogonal design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_orthogonal_design). Better to combine your `users_achievements` and `users_deductions` tables, such that `users_rewards_logged.reward_id` is FK into the combined table which could have a column indicating whether each reward is an achievement or a deduction (I'd suggest a `points` column containing 1 and -1 respectively, so that one can merely join, group and sum).

Comment: So, it's not really used by kids!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that gets the above desired results:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ua.name, ud.name) AS reward,
  SUM(url.points) AS points, COUNT(url.logged_id) AS count
FROM users_rewards_logged url
LEFT JOIN users_deductions ud
  ON ud.deduction_id = url.reward_id
  AND url.type = 1
LEFT JOIN users_achievements ua
  ON ua.achievement_id = url.reward_id
  AND url.type = 2
GROUP BY url.reward_id, url.type
```

Your SQLFiddle had the order of `points` and `type` in the wrong order for the table `users_rewards_logged`.

Here's the fixed [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5134e/10) with the result:

```
reward      points  count
Good Work      100      1
Rude           -50      2
```

Comment: Great stuff guys this looks to be bang on the money - at some point I may look to modify the db structure but for now this does what I need. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Although eggyal is correct--this is rather bad design for your data--what you ask can be done, but requires a UNION clause:

```
    SELECT users_achievements.name, users_rewards_logged.points, COUNT(*)
    FROM users_rewards_logged
    INNER JOIN users_achievements ON users_achievements.achievement_id = users_rewards_logged.reward_id
WHERE users_rewards_logged.type = 2
    UNION
    SELECT users_deductions.name, users_rewards_logged.points, COUNT(*)
    FROM users_rewards_logged
    INNER JOIN users_deductions ON users_deductions.deduction_id = users_rewards_logged.reward_id
WHERE users_rewards_logged.type = 1
    GROUP BY 1, 2
```

There's no reason NOT to combine the achievements and deductions tables and just use non-conflicting codes.  If you combined the tables, then you would no longer need the UNION clause--your query would be MUCH simpler.

Comment: Doesn't **require** a UNION. Also, check that GROUP BY clause. What does `GROUP BY 1, 2` mean? Also, seems like you'd want UNION ALL over UNION. What happens if there's more than one achievement or deduction?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you have two tables (`users_deductions` and `users_achievements`) that defines the type of reward. As @eggyal stated, you are violating the principle of orthogonal design, which causes the lack of normalization of your schema.

So, I have combined the tables `users_deductions` and `users_achievements` in one table called `reward_type`.

The result is in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/813d5/6

Comment: i agree - the design isn't great, its a legacy design so can't really modify the table structures at the moment

Comment: @Zabs, if you only want good ways to do it with the existing design, you should state that in the question.

Comment: @Marcus sorry I should have mentioned that but all the comments are still valid & useful however :-)